# Selenium via Java - click on checkbox different response than manual clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium, checkbox

I am having an issue clicking on a specific checkbox where it should check all the other check-boxes below it (root parameter).
It used to work when I used this code on the element:

```
arguments[0].click();
```

I have tried to use normal `click` method but it does not work, I also tried to use:

```
("document.getElementById('" + checkBoxID + "').checked=true");
("document.getElementById('" + checkBoxID + "').onchange();")
```

What I have found is when I'm triggering the click by `JS` , the response is different than if i'd click on the checkbox manually .
It is worth mentioning that clicking manually on the checkbox does trigger the event correctly and the other checkbox's below the main checkbox are checked as-well.
Are there any other possible ways to trigger the `onchange` event? I tried to force `onchange` with this command:

```
document.getElementById("test").onchange()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: onchange is an event handler. You cannot call it like this to call the system event.

Comment: How can I resolve this issue then?

Comment: What happened when did you click by selenium method `click()`???

Comment: Hey @SaurabhGaur , when i am trying to click it i get exception 'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 15.09 seconds' , i tried to check and the element is not dispalyed, that is the reason why it is happening, is there a way with JS to make the element count as displayed so i can click on it normally ?

Comment: @ZvikaNadav Oh i see.. means you want to make it visible first.. Right??

Comment: If there is a way to make is visible, maybe the selenium command will work as intended. @SaurabhGaur

Comment: I posted the answer but it will trigger mouse event to the checkbox.. let try it first.. If it doesn't work then let me know

Comment: For make it visible..could you share your exact HTML for you check box first??

Comment: I will share the specific checkbox html where the issue occurs as soon as the environment will be up for me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you are saying selenium `click()` does not as work expected, you should try using `JavascriptExecutor` to trigger `MouseEvents` as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("checkboxId"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver
executor.executeScript("function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {"
                        + "var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');"
                        + "clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);"
                        + "node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);"
                        + "}triggerMouseEvent (arguments[0], 'mouseover');"
            + "triggerMouseEvent (arguments[0], 'mousedown');"
            + "triggerMouseEvent (arguments[0], 'mouseup');"
            + "triggerMouseEvent (arguments[0], 'click');", el);
```

**Edited1** :- If you want to make you checkbox visible using `executeScript` and want to perform using `selenium` `click()`, try as below :-

```
el = (WebElement)executor.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';return arguments[0];", el);
el.click();
```

**Edited2** :- I think you are not pointing correct check box to click as I seeing in your provided HTML checkbox id may be dynamically generated, you should implement `WebDriverWait` ti wait until checkbox visibile as below :-

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver
WebElement el = (WebElement)executor.executeScript("return document.getElementById('flattendListproductLinesTree|1@innerVO@isSelected')");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(el)));
el.click();
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have tried to make the checkbox visible but it is not working, the element is still not displayed after running `el = (WebElement)executor.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';return arguments[0];", el);
el.click();`

Comment: @ZvikaNadav did you tried first option to trigger event??

Comment: @ZvikaNadav I have provided only generic way to make element visible..You need to share you checkbox HTML.. that i want to see by which style it is inviisble that's why I could make it visible

Comment: Here is the checkbox html : `<input id="flattendListproductLinesTree|1@innerVO@isSelected" type="checkbox" onchange="updateElementTitle(this);if($('#' + this.id + 'Hidden').exists()){$('#' + this.id + 'Hidden').val(this.checked)};performAjaxAction('changeIsSelectedForTree')" jsonid="productLinesTree@innerVO@isSelected|0" name="unknown" style="background-color: rgb(255, 121, 96);" title="false">`

Comment: @ZvikaNadav As I seeing there is no style set which could make it invisible?? Is  it seems as Invisible into your website??

Comment: Not at all, it is visible . Also, wanted to let you know that your first answer is not working in for that case as-well :(

Comment: @ZvikaNadav please try once with provided first javascript to trigger click event and let me know..

Comment: @ZvikaNadav Ok I think you check id has dynamically generated, you should try with `WebDriverWait`.. try with updated answer..

Comment: flattendListproductLinesTree|1@innerVO@isSelected id is not dynamically generated the 1 is for the first checkbox in the table, it does not change.

Comment: @ZvikaNadav Ok may be problem with the id which contains `|` seperator, try to locate it using js and wait until it visible.. try with last updated answer and let me know..

Comment: the id does not turn into visible, i tried your command and it is not the case, it is staying as invisible...FYI `el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(el)));` has issue where visibilityOf need to get By parameter ( tried to copy paste execute it) and i had to cast the parameter to (By)...

Comment: @ZvikaNadav `visibilityOf` expeact `WebElement` as param...For clarification Have a look on selenium docs..https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-

Comment: Tried it, got timeout exception `Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@66b014f3 -> unknown locator]`

Comment: Thanks for keep trying by the way,very appreciated,  any other suggestions you may think about?Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to inject a different onchange functionality, I tried on a different environment and it looks like the onchange is different there -  `<input id="flattendListproductLinesTree|1@innerVO@isSelected" type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementById(this.id + 'Hidden').value = this.checked;performAjaxAction('changeIsSelectedForTree')" jsonid="productLinesTree@innerVO@isSelected|0" name="unknown" style="background-color: rgb(255, 121, 96);">`

Comment: @ZvikaNadav once execute this into your browser console `document.getElementById('flattendListproductLinesTree|1@innerVO@isSelectedHidden')` and let me know the result

Comment: The result is null

Comment: means this is the problem...when you are going to clicked to the checkbox it goes to modify element which has id `flattendListproductLinesTree|1@innerVO@isSelectedHidde‌​n` but it could not find it...

Comment: @ZvikaNadav what happened when you are going to manually click??

Comment: It is working as expected, here's the HTML after manually clicking the checkbox `<input id="flattendListproductLinesTree|1@innerVO@isSelected" type="checkbox" onchange="updateElementTitle(this);if($('#' + this.id + 'Hidden').exists()){$('#' + this.id + 'Hidden').val(this.checked)};performAjaxAction('changeIsSelectedForTree')" jsonid="productLinesTree@innerVO@isSelected|0" name="unknown" style="background-color: rgb(255, 121, 96);" title="true">`

Comment: Isn't the onchange functionality look different to you with the other comment i provided from other application i tried to copy the html of the same checkbox, maybe that is the reason?

Comment: @ZvikaNadav No it's functionality of on-change similar to above provided, Difference only here get the hidden element using `Jquery`..

Comment: So frustrating...Any other idea maybe?Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share your website??

Comment: I am sorry but i can't share it. Thanks

Comment: Any other ideas came up ? I am still facing this issue sadly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function simulateClick() { 
var event = new MouseEvent('click',     { 'view': window, 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true }); //creates a mouse event
var cb =  document.getElementById('checkbox');     var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(event); //fires the event.
}
```

Example from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).To run the javascript code using selenium see the next answer...

Comment: This is basically a code only answer which is frowned upon on SO. Please take a minute to describe what the code does and how it answers the question so OP and future readers can better understand.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, but as @JeffC said, its only code answer, i wish to better understand it and what it does.Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please explain how to I implement it for my code i tried to change the checkbox to the relevant ID , thanks.

Comment: Hey, I am still waiting for your response, sadly i am still facing the same issue with the checkboxs